# Google APIs Java Client not working with PlayStore build

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-drive-android-api

I am authorizing with the `Google APIs Java Client`, upon successful authorization I call `com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v3-rev82-1.22.0` to fetch all the drive files.

I have registered on `console.developers.google.com`
with two `OAuth 2.0` client IDs (`Dev` and `Prod SHA-`1 signing-certificate fingerprint)

Everything works fine when I sign the builds and test on both dev and prod until its submitted to play store.

After downloading the App from play store the drive does not work, it gets to the point where the user is prompted to select the google account they want to use and then fails.

Upon checking the logs I could see the below errors, which I believe fails at authentication

> W/Auth: [GetToken,GetTokenResponse] error status:
>
> W/Auth: [GetToken] GetToken failed with status code: Unknown

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the status code is returned Unknown. actually its UNREGISTERED_ON_API_CONSOLE

If you enroll your app into the Google Play App Signing program, Google removes your certificate and creates a new signing certificate.

In the Play Console go to Release Management -> App signing

If you opted in to Google Play App Signing, you'll see 2 certificates there.Use the App Signing Certificate fingerprint instead of the Upload Certificate.

Copy the SHA-1 from App signing certificate and create another OAuth 2.0 client ID in console.developers.google.com